# How to write a formula that references a cell and counts up every time the referenced cell is a "1"?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Im trying to reference a column called "Channel" and have the active cell, which is under the column "Terminal" stay consistent for the amount of points there are in the channel, and then add one number and do the same thing.

So I have a column named "Channel" and this column continues to count from 1-8 and restarts every time another set of a channel is added. Sometimes it can restart after reaching 4, and that is based on some specifics that are irrelevant to the question. So an example would be that the "terminal" column populates like this: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2...

I used an if statement, but it doesnt add 2 and 3 when needed

=IFS(L10>=1,1)

and then i tried this one to add the extra number, but i dont think it recognizes the value of the cell

=IFS(L11>=1,1,L11=1,M10+1)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a standard IF with Max().  Put this in M2 and copy down:

```
=IF(L2=1,MAX($M$1:M1)+1,M1)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Works well....  I just changed the values of the cells it referenced bc i need it to start at M4, but it works great!

Answer (score 1):

Put this formulat into M2, and fill down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(L$2:L2=L2))
```